# Save me in writing queries

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am quite a newbie to the IT industry, and therefore, would be delightful to get some help in writing queries (in Redshift).

I tried to find out 1) how many users were joined to our service in February, 2) which users revisited after the day they joined, if they did then when? (i.e. day1, day2, day3,..., and so on), and 3) how many read/impression were acquired by each users at the day of visits.

The below are the tables and relevant columns I have been provided.

```
The tables and relevant columns I have been provided are as following
   I) users:             id      created_at 
                        4,578,001  2018-05-16 00:02
                        4,578,002  2018-05-16 00:02
                        4,578,007  2018-05-16 00:10

   II) user_content_action_by_traffic_source:  id         created_at    action_type 
                                            4,428,830  2018-05-16 00:00   read 
                                            3,154,331  2018-05-16 00:00   read
                                              714,795  2018-05-16 00:00 impression 

where the column 'created_at in I)' shows the date of account created, 
and the column 'created_at in II)' shows the date of action recorded (i.e. a user reads a post)

  - Example codes with the above tables:
     SELECT u.created_at,
            u.id,
            SUM(CASE WHEN s.action_type = 'read' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS read,
            SUM(CASE WHEN s.action_type = 'impression' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS impression
     FROM users u INNER JOIN user_content_action_by_traffic_source s ON u.id = s.user_id
     WHERE u.created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '2 days'
     GROUP BY 1, 2
     ORDER BY 1
     LIMIT 10
  - Example output:    created_at        id       read      impression  
                   2018-05-16 00:00   4,577,999    2           38
                   2018-05-16 00:01   4,578,000    1           77
                   2018-05-16 00:02   4,578,001    2           48
```

The below codes are what I firstly wrote (and I know that mine isn't good tho)

```
WITH t1 (SELECT convert_timezone('Asia/Seoul', u.created_at) AS created_at,
                u.id AS new_user,
                COUNT(DISTINCT date_trunc('day', convert_timezone('Asia/Seoul', action.created_at))) AS num_of_days_visited
         FROM users u JOIN user_content_action_by_traffic_source action ON u.id = action.user_id
         WHERE DATE(u.created_at) >= '2018-02-01' 
               AND DATE(u.created_at) <= '2018-02-28'  
           AND action.created_at >= u.created_at
              AND action.created_at <= u.created_at + INTERVAL '4 weeks'
         GROUP BY 1, 2
         ORDER BY 1, 2)

SELECT DATE(t1.created_at),
       t1.new_user,
       DATE(convert_timezone('Asia/Seoul', action.created_at)) AS date_visited,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action.action_type = 'read' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Read,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action.action_type = 'impression' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Imp
FROM t1 JOIN user_content_action_by_traffic_source action ON t1.new_user = action.user_id
WHERE convert_timezone('Asia/Seoul', action.created_at) >= t1.created_at
      AND convert_timezone('Asia/Seoul', action.created_at) <= t1.created_at + INTERVAL '4 weeks'
  AND action.content_type = 'post'
  AND t1.num_of_days_visited = 2
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Note that the city where I work at is Seoul/Korea whilst the timezone for date record is based in the US.

The following outcomes were

```
        date     new_user   date_visited  read  imp
   1 2018-02-01   4432986    2018-02-02    2     8 
   2 2018-02-01   4432987    2018-02-02    5     49
   3 2018-02-01   4432987    2018-02-26    1     0
   4 2018-02-01   4432992    2018-02-02    6    169
```

My desirable outcomes would be

```
        date     new_user   date_visited  read  imp  date_visited_2   read2  imp2
   1 2018-02-01   4432986    2018-02-02    2     8 
   2 2018-02-01   4432987    2018-02-02    5     49    2018-02-26       1     0 
   3 2018-02-01   4432992    2018-02-02    6    169
```

If my description of the codes or sample data lacks information then please leave some comment.

Thanks

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results.

Comment: Please provide a sample input table (with only required columns) and a sample of the output you would expect, based upon that sample data.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I added some details about information I have. I wish these would be sufficient enough for you to get some ideas. Cheers

Comment: To clarify: Please show some sample data in the tables, and the desired output _for that specific data_. Your desired output above does not seem to be related to your sample data.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for your quick reply. I once again edited the table given. Would that be what you expected to see? Thx

Comment: No -- Your input samples (at the top) show a date of 2018-05-16, but your output (at the bottom) shows 2018-02-01 and 2018-02-02. It is not possible to get that output from the input.

Comment: For an example of a question that provided sample input and output, see: [Redshift create all the combinations of any length for the values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50417666/174777)